# how i can get data query cake php in array var_dump?

Tags: php, oracle, cakephp, var-dump

i have a query in cake php

```
$sql ="select menu from ms_menu";
$result=advancedQuery($sql); 
foreach ($result as $data ){
    echo $data[0];
}
```

the case is :
the `$data[0]` show nothing ...

i try to

```
var_dump $result;
```

and the result is

output

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["NAMA_MENU"]=> string(6)  "Report" } } }
```

i need to get "Report" to my variabel..

anyone knows the problem ?? please help

Comment: There is nothing Cake about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, `var_dump();` is a function and you should use it like this : `var_dump($result);`

Here is your information hierarchy :

```
- $data
-- $data[0]
--- $data[0][0]
---- $data[0][0]['NAMA_MENU']
```

Here, you are trying to `echo` an **array** (`$data[0]`). It's not possible.

You can :

— Create a double recursive foreach :

```
foreach ($result as $data ){
    foreach ($data[0] as $innerData ){
        echo $innerData['NAMA_MENU'];
    }  
}
```

— Get directly your needed value inside the first `foreach` :

```
foreach ($result as $data ){
    echo $data[0][0]['NAMA_MENU'];
}
```